# 404 Not Found at port 443

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have looked around the web for solution to my 404 error, and i can not seem to get a solution.
so this is a sample of my .htaccess file

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Installation directory
# RewriteBase /
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

when i use the sample project in xamp on windows 10 it works fine. Now when i got to ubuntu 18 and install LAMP onto the server and load the project, the home page loads well but when i begin going to other pages i get an error of 404. I checked the other solutions it involves changing the apache2.conf file. but since my problem is in port 443 and not port 80. do i have to change a different file instead.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you installed and enabled `mod_rewrite` for Apache on the server? There's no difference regarding these kind of rewrites for http and https.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i already did that

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you enabled mod_rewrite? Have you added: `AllowOverride All` on the vhost (Apache config)? That's needed for Apache to actually use the htaccess. Check [this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14362475/2453432) for more info

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i always restarted the apache server. when i change AllowOverride All i get 500 internal error

Comment: A 500 error might be some progress. Check your web servers error log and see if there are any error messages that can shred some light over the issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson found the solution from the server logs, i had to enable headers